# How can I withdraw the days of a month in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

```
select l.id, l.surname, l.fname, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS('02.03.2013', -2)) + level, 
TO_CHAR(T.fdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') FDATE from pers_log t, pers_list l 
where t.id=l.id and t.id='1316' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE level <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS('02.09.2013', -1)) - LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS('02.09.2013', -2))
```

I have written a query in the form. but entered an infinite loop. Despite the wait for a long time does not return a result.
I do not understand where I'm wrong ...
(Please note that the days of the month)

```
21 aaaa bbbbb 01.08.2013  (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
2 aaaa bbbbb 02.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
23 aaaa bbbbb 03.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
null null null 04.08.2013 
55 aaaa bbbbb 05.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
null null null 06.08.2013 
....
null null null 27.08.2013 
28 aaaa bbbbb 28.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
null null null 29.08.2013 
60 aaaa bbbbb 30.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
51 aaaa bbbbb 31.08.2013 (note:pers_log fdate is not null)
```

---

The following is not a problem after all, but I could not find the reason to enter an infinite loop like the above query organized.

```
select l.id, l.surname, l.fname 
TO_CHAR(T.fdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') FDATE from pers_log t, pers_list l 
and to_char(t.FDATE, 'YYYY')='2013' and to_char(t.FDATE, 'MM')='08' and t.id='1316' 
order by FDATE asc

21 aaaa bbbbb 01.08.2013  
2 aaaa bbbbb 02.08.2013 
23 aaaa bbbbb 03.08.2013 
55 aaaa bbbbb 05.08.2013 
28 aaaa bbbbb 28.08.2013 
60 aaaa bbbbb 30.08.2013 
51 aaaa bbbbb 31.08.2013
```

What are the results of the query as I wrote above, the following query returns an error, cause and effect, but

Comment: Not sure if you're going to finish the question you left hanging, but it's hard to understand quite what you mean. There aren't any loops, so is it just not returning after a long time, or is this running inside a PL/SQL loop? You started to mention an error but didn't show it. The first query seems confused about whether it's for March or September. And your IDs look like they should be numbers, so forcing them to strings (`'1316'`) might slow things down a bit, if the tables are big, though you don't appear to have data for `1316` anyway. Have you run an explain plan to see what's happening?

Comment: all the days of my intention to take a month, and day of the month, if my table (id, fname, surname, date), but if you do not return them to null as a result of the query expression nor the result is what a mistake entering an infinite loop

Comment: `21 aaaa bbbbb 01.08.2013  
2 aaaa bbbbb 02.08.2013 
23 aaaa bbbbb 03.08.2013 
null null null 04.08.2013 
55 aaaa bbbbb 05.08.2013 
null null null 06.08.2013 
....
null null null 27.08.2013 
28 aaaa bbbbb 28.08.2013 
null null null 29.08.2013 
60 aaaa bbbbb 30.08.2013 
51 aaaa bbbbb 31.08.2013 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still finding it hard to work out what you're trying to do, but I *think* you mean you want to list all the days in the month before the query date, and show matching data from `pers_log and`pers_list` if it exists, and null otherwise?

If so this is the kind of thing you'd need:

```
select t.id, l.surname, l.fname, to_char(x.target_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
from (
  select last_day(add_months(to_date('02.09.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), -2))
    + level as target_date
  from dual
  connect by level <= last_day(add_months(to_date('02.09.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), -1))
    - last_day(add_months(to_date('02.09.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), -2))
) x
left join pers_log t on t.fdate = x.target_date
  and t.id=1316
left join pers_list l on l.id = t.id
order by x.target_date;
```

The inner select generates all the dates for the previous month as an inline view that I've unimaginatively called `x`. Then to get possible matching data I've used outer joins to your real tables, which means nulls will be shown if there is no match.

If `fdate` has a time component then you'll need to ignore that in the join condition. You can either do:

```
on trunc(t.fdate) = x.target_date
```

or

```
on t.fdate >= x.target_date and t.fdate < x.target_date + 1
```

Of course, I may be way out on what you're actually doing. Your original query isn't filtering the dates at all as there is no join between them, so you're probably getting a lot of results back - I think it's just got a lot more data than you expect and is therefore taking a lot longer to retrieve the data. That's not the same as an infinite loop, but I don't see where you can actually be having a loop.

Comment: Inquiry into an infinite loop, but tried to understand why my testimony. thank you very much indeed